# Deleting matrix elements by = [] vs reassigning matrix

Tags: matlab

Is there any difference between these two methods for deleting elements in Matlab:

```
ElementsToDelete = [0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0]

A = 1:10
A(ElementsToDelete) = []

%Versus

A = 1:10
A = A(~ElementsToDelete)
```

Are there times when one method is more appropriate than the other? Is there a difference in efficiency? Or are they completely interchangeable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
A = rand(1e3, 1);
b = A<0.5;

tic; 
for ii = 1:1e5
    a = A;       
    a(b) = [];
end
toc

tic; 
for ii = 1:1e5
    a = A;        
    a = a(~b);
end
toc
```

Results:

```
Elapsed time is 1.654146 seconds
Elapsed time is 1.126325 seconds
```

So the difference is a speed factor of 1.5 in favour of re-assigning. This however, is worse:

```
A = rand(1e4, 1);

stop = 0;    
for jj = 1:10
    a = A;
    start = tic;
    for ii = 1:1e5
        a(a < rand) = [];
    end
    stop = stop + toc(start);
end
avg1 = stop/10


stop = 0;    
for jj = 1:10
    a = A;
    start = tic;
    for ii = 1:1e5
        a = a(a > rand);
    end
    stop = stop + toc(start);
end
avg2 = stop/10

avg1/avg2
```

Results:

```
avg1 = 1.1740235 seconds
avg2 = 0.1850463 seconds

avg1/avg2 = 6.344485136963019
```

So, the factor's increased to well over 6.

My guess is that deletion (i.e., assigning with `[]`) re-writes the entire array on each and every occurrence of a `true` in the internal loop through the logical indices. This is hopelessly inefficient, as becomes apparent when testing it like this. Re-assigning on the other hand can determine the size of the new array beforehand and initialize it accordingly; no re-writes needed.

Why the JIT does not compile the one into the other is a mystery to me, because deletion is a far more intuitive notation IMHO. But, as you see, it is inefficient compared to alternatives, and should thus be used sparingly. **Never use it inside loops!**

Comment: Any argument to be made for the =[] approach?

Comment: Note that putting the `~` outside the loop makes the second version even faster.

Comment: @H.Muster Yes, but that wouldn't be fair to the first version :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: I just noted that by moving `b = a<0.5;` out of the loop, the first version is about as fast as the second. Is there a specific reason why the index is calculated at every iteration in the first version?

Comment: @H.Muster No, that was just a silly copy-paste error. See my new edit.

Comment: Yes I have always use the deletion notation as I also find it more intuitive but maybe the time has come to switch over. Thanks.

Comment: The second example above is not a reliable measure since (1) `b = A < 1/ii*rand;` in the first loop will become a vector of all 0s for large ii (around 100 or so) and `A(b)=[]` would not be doing anything. (2) A different random A is used for each for-loop; one data point for elapsed times is inconclusive in this case. For repeated runs, you get a large variation of elapsed times.

Comment: @Kavka 1/1e5 is 1e-5; definitely not zero. And the test is intended to indicate that re-assignment is much faster than deletion. You are right to say that it's not precise to run the tests only once, but I wasn't after precision here, just principles. Nevertheless, I'll update the tests.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis The last edit makes the performance comparison more reliable.