# how to remove specific rows in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

I have a matrix A , I want to remove the rows that has similar values `(1,1)`, `(2,2)`, `(3,3)`

```
A =
     1     1
     2     1
     3     1
     1     2
     2     2
     1     3
     3     3
```

so the matrix would be like this

```
 2     1
 3     1
 1     2
 1     3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach without calling any function:

```
 A = A(A(:,1) == A(:,2),:)
```

Efficiency of this approach vs the solution based on **diff()**:

```
n = 10;
y = [round(rand(n,1)) round(rand(n,1))];

tic;
for i = 1:1e4
  A = y;
  A(diff(A,[],2)~=0,:);
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.091990 seconds.

tic;
for i = 1:1e4
  A = y;
  A = A(A(:,1) == A(:,2),:);
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.037842 seconds.



% Suggestion of @Dan in the comments
tic;
for i = 1:1e4
  A = y;
  A(A(:,1) == A(:,2),:) = [];
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.147636 seconds.
```

Comment: Or `A = A(A(:,1) ~= A(:,2),:)` as the `=[]` approach can be inefficient: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421345/deleting-matrix-elements-by-vs-reassigning-matrix

Comment: You should include your original in your time comparison for interests sake and future visitors

Answer (score 4):

One approach using `diff` -

```
A(diff(A,[],2)~=0,:)
```

For a general `NXM` case, where `M` is the number of columns of `A`, one can extend this as -

```
A(any(diff(A,[],2)~=0,2),:)
```

Thus, if you have

```
A= [1 1 1; 
    2 2 3; 
    3 1 4;
    8 1 2; 
    2 2 2; 
    1 3 1; 
    3 3 3]
```

You would get -

```
 2     2     3
 3     1     4
 8     1     2
 1     3     1
```