# How to remove specific elements of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, math, matrix

I am having a bad day at work. I have a very simple question.

I have 2x100 matrix such that

```
[1 2 3 4 5  6 -2 -3 ....

 2 4 5 3 2 -4  3  3 ...]
```

What I would like to do is that to check the first row of the matrix and delete all the numbers greater than 2 and delete the corresponding entry in the row2. So for example if there is only 1 element than in upper case our matrix will become a 2x99 matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use logical indexing:

```
idxToKeep   = yourMat(1, :) <= 2;

newMat      = yourMat(:, idxToKeep);
```

or in case you don't want to create a new matrix:

```
yourMat     = yourMat(:, idxToKeep);
```

or all in  a one-liner:

```
yourMat     = yourMat(:, yourMat(1, :) <= 2);
```

Comment: @Dan I agree, if it was my own code I would do so. However, I think this is easer for TS to understand. I'll add it...

Comment: I'll just add one more for reference: `a(:,a(1,:)<=0.2) = [];` works too. In case anyone wonders; no, it's not faster, and I recommend one of Nick's solutions. =)

Comment: @RobertP. I think you wanted `> 2`? Also it is indeed slower: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421345/deleting-matrix-elements-by-vs-reassigning-matrix

Comment: @RobertP. Wow... that's just ugly :P

Comment: @Dan: yes of course, little mix-up, and Nick: yes, it is =P