# Command for delete first few rows in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let's say

n =

```
       1
       2
    1767
    1768
    1769
    1770
    1771
    1772
    1773
    1774
    1775
    1776
```

and I want n to be like

n=

```
    1767
    1768
    1769
    1770
    1771
    1772
    1773
    1774
    1775
    1776
```

this is just for an example. 
I want to make command for general application.
The data over 100 is valid.
Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all the numbers below `100` then:

```
n = n(n <= 100);
```

Comment: @CitizenInsane that is slower though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421345/deleting-matrix-elements-by-vs-reassigning-matrix

Comment: Yes this is just an example. I want to remove first few rows below 100. And make over 100 rows to be the first row

Comment: @leaving_traces are they always sorted / are you sure all the numbers you want to delete will be at the beginining?

Comment: @leaving_traces then it's very simple using logical indexing. see my edit. btw, this is an extremely basic Matlab question, you should probably go through some basic tutorials before you continue