# Remove rows from a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the array "A" with values:

```
101                 101
0                   0
61.6320000000000    0.725754779522671
73.7000000000000    0.830301150185882
78.2800000000000    0.490917508345341
81.2640000000000    0.602561200211232
82.6880000000000    0.435568593909153
```

And I wish to remove this first row and retain the shape of the array (2 columns), thus creating the array

```
0                   0
61.6320000000000    0.725754779522671
73.7000000000000    0.830301150185882
78.2800000000000    0.490917508345341
81.2640000000000    0.602561200211232
82.6880000000000    0.435568593909153
```

I have used `A = A(A~=101);` , which removes the values as required - however it packs the array down to one column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is:

```
A = A(2:end, :)
```

But you can also do

```
A(1,:) = []
```

however it is slightly less efficient (see [Deleting matrix elements by = [] vs reassigning matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421345/deleting-matrix-elements-by-vs-reassigning-matrix))

If you are looking to delete rows that equal a certain number try

```
A = A(A(:,1)~=101,:)
```

Use `all` or `any` if you want to delete row if either all or any column equals your value:

```
A = A(all(A~=101,2),:)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. I've used it a few times since you taught me ^^