# Delete rows and columns of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have the matrix below:

```
a = [1  2  1  4; 
     3  4  9  16; 
     0  0 -2 -4; 
     0  0 -6 -8]
```

How can I arbitrary remove any given rows or columns? for example second row and third column of the above matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [slightly more efficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421345/deleting-matrix-elements-by-vs-reassigning-matrix) (although possibly more complicated to set up) is to reassign all the rows you want to keep (when compared with setting the rows you want to delete to the empty matrix). So for example if you want to delete rows 5 and 7 from a matrix you can either do

```
A = A([1:4, 6, 8:end],:)
```

or

```
A = A(setdiff(1:size(A,1), [5,7] ),:)
```

but the best method is likely to use logical indexing (which is often a natural step in Matlab workflows anyway):

```
idx = true(size(A,1),1);
idx([5,7]) = false;

A = A(idx,:)
```

Comment: I believe you have a misspelled ':' in your first line of code.

Comment: @AndrasDeak thanks, feel free to edit answers if you spot obvious errors like that.

Comment: I just realized that your solution is not only faster (which was new to me), but it can solve the asker's full problem in one command: deleting rows and columns simultaneously. With assignment to `[]` you can only do that in 2 steps, since the object to delete is not an array. OK, you could use `sub2ind`, but that's unreasonably messy.

Comment: I agree with your opinion of doing the suppression in once, but we need to do more work to suppress at once some rows AND some columns.

Comment: @Bentoy13 probably still easier and more readable to do the rows and the columns separately?

Comment: @Dan Hum yes. I am making some tests, where I create the whole mask of kept values (with bsxfun), it seems that within my first tests it's about 2 times slower than deleting rows then columns.

Comment: @Bentoy13 you don't have to do the whole mask btw just `A([1,3:end],[1:2, end])` or `A([true false true true],[true true false true])`

Comment: @Dan ... I missed _this_ obvious ... must be tired now. Ok, run the test now. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Just assign the column or line to the empty matrix:

```
a(2,:) = [];
a(:,3) = [];
```

**Note** : I compare the [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31727629/1507014) to mine, following the link put inside. On a big array (created as `rand(1e4)`) and on 10 runs where I delete 2 columns and 2 rows, the average times are 0.932ms for the empty-matrix assignment, and 0.905ms for the kept-row (or -column) assignment. So the gap seen there is not as big as 1.5x mentioned in the link. Always perform a little benchmark first :) !

**Edit** Fastest solution is to create the index mask for rows and columns, and reassign your array with these masks. Ex:

```
a = rand(10000);
kr = true(size(a,1),1);
kr([72,6144]) = false;    % some rows to delete
kc = true(1,size(a,2));
kc([1894,4512]) = false;  % some columns to delete
a = a(kr,kc);
```

On this test, it's clearly twice faster than performing the suppression on rows and columns separately.