# Remove specific integers from matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a `matrix <1x1000>` containing integers. It contain the value 150 a couple of times and I want to remove that value completely. Any ideas how to?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all elements that equal `150` then

```
M = M(M ~= 150)
```

If you want to remove all elements belonging to a list of undesired numbers then

```
list = [150, 230, 420]
M = M(~ismember(M, list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Same but different expression

```
M(M==150)=[];

list = [150,230,420];
M(ismember(M,list))=[];
```

When you type A(index)=[], it delete A(index). For example,

```
A = [1,2,3];
A(2) = [];
```

Then

```
A = [1,3]
```

Comment: It's slower to do it this way (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421345/deleting-matrix-elements-by-vs-reassigning-matrix)